# Unable to get option to export, when more than 3k rows in PHPMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I am using the following query, results get 9k rows but unable to get the export option in phpmyadmin.

But when put less data in search like 300/200 it's showing. why export option not there for large data.

Can you help in this case, please.

```
SELECT * FROM `t` WHERE `BA No.` IN ('1','2',.........)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just to be clear you are using PHPMYADMIN export and it exports 3K of 9K rows, or does it not export anything?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes it does not export anything. and also there is no export option there.